# Не сохраняет в .csv file

Tags: python, csv

Сохраняю в массив `project`.

Не могу сохранит в `.csv`, пишет `writerow()` через запятую, из массива `project` нет контента.

Где может быть ошибка?

```
def get_parse(html):
       soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
       hrefs = soup.find_all('a', class_='address')

for inc,aa in enumerate(hrefs, start=1):
    soup= BS(get_html(aa.get('href')), 'lxml')
    rot = soup.find_all('a', class_="green dhide")
    project = []
    for ii in rot:
        namber = ii.text
        project.append({
            'Modile' : namber
            })
        return (project)

def save(project, path):
    with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(('Namber modile'))
    for lists in project:
        writer.writerow(lists['Mobile'])

def main():
project = []        
for page in range(1, 2):
    base_url = url + 'page=%d'% page + '&size=10'
    inc = get_parse(get_html(base_url))
save(project, 'mob_tel.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: Код не принято показывать в виде картинок, замените картинку вашим кодом (кнопка `править`). Если при выполнении кода произошла ошибка, то добавьте ее текст в вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: Картинку заменил кодом. Ошибки нет, не сохраняет.

Comment: Спасибо, что заменили, так намного удобнее стало. Вот только разъехалось в коде форматирование и код стал невалидный, поправьте, пожалуйста, отступы. А так, я сразу заметил что у вас несколько переменных `project = []`, скорее всего вам нужно `project = []` передавать параметром внутрь `get_parse`, а тот `project = []`, что внутри функции удалить

Comment: Если переменной не присваивать значения, то его и не будет.

Comment: Результатов нет. project = [] передавал параметром внутрь get_parse, а  project = [], что внутри функции удалил.

Comment: 1. Исправьте код в вопросе на тот, который запускаете. 2. Поправьте его форматирование.

Comment: Ну и хороший способ проверить, действительно ли вы что-то сохраняете в массив project - вывести его на печать. Наверняка окажется, что ничего вы туда не сохраняете, поэтому и сохранять в csv нечего.

Comment: for inc,aa in enumerate(hrefs, start=1):
    soup= BS(get_html(aa.get('href')), 'lxml')
    rot = soup.find_all('a', class_="green dhide")
    project = []
    for ii in rot:
        namber = ii.text
        project.append({
            'Modile' : namber
            })
        print (project)  есть список

Comment: в main: print(project) пустой